# How to edit DefualtTableCellRenderer in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am having a problem with editing the `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.

I would like to right align just the 2nd column in my table. However, the code below  right aligns all the columns, and not just the 2nd one!

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
for (int i=0; i < tblMenu.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++) 
{ 
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = 
        (DefaultTableCellRenderer) tblMenu.getCellRenderer(i, 1);

    renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default renderer on your table with an anonymous inner class.  Something like the following (untested) code might work:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (column == 2) {
                setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
            }
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }

    });
```

Comment: As it is one renderer that is shared for all columns of type `Object` you should reset the alignment in an `else` branch. In fact I would store the value (`Component c = super.getTableCellRenderer...`), set the alignment and return the component, so the alignment can't be overwritten in the super call.

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful, useful and i will also be able to adapt it later on if i so wish to! =D

Comment: oh and his, you are right you do need to add an else in there to reverse the change! =D

Answer (score 1):

All columns use the same renderer by default, you need to provide a differently configured one for the column you want to change:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer righty = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
righty.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

tblMenu.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(righty);
```

Maybe a little simpler than A Lee's way (depending on how much other customization you're doing).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it works perfectly and describes why mine did not work properly! However, i am going to give best answer to A Lee! Thanks though!! =D

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cell renderer for a specific column. All you have to do is get the table's columnModel, then get the specific column, then call setCellRenderer for that column.

But even easier, if your column holds numeric data, simply override the table model's `getColumnClass(...)` to return Integer.class for that column and the table will format correctly for you. Or if you know your table will not be empty, simply let the table's data tell the world what type of type it is and let the JTable render things as best it should:

```
// if the table isn't empty, this will work.
class MyDTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
  public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int c) {
     return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
  }
}
```